# EWS .msg file attachments

Tags: c#

I have a situation where i have to download the attachments of .msg files.i have tried saving the attachments into .eml files.But i wanted to download the attachments of .msg files as well.Any Code snippets will be helpful. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For Saving Attachments in EWS Client C#:
Please check the below code: 
I have applied search criteria to lookup email having attachment after "06/25/2019 4:00"

```
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
        service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
        service.AutodiscoverUrl("MAILID");

        Mailbox mb = new Mailbox("MAILID");

        FolderId fid = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, mb);

        Folder inbox = Folder.Bind(service, fid);

        ItemView view = new ItemView(1000);
        view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ItemSchema.Subject, ItemSchema.DateTimeSent);

        PropertySet PropSet = new PropertySet();
        PropSet.Add(ItemSchema.Subject);
        PropSet.Add(ItemSchema.Body);
        PropSet.Add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived);
        PropSet.Add(EmailMessageSchema.From);
        PropSet.Add(EmailMessageSchema.Attachments);
        PropSet.Add(EmailMessageSchema.HasAttachments);
        PropSet.RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text;
        //PropSet.Add(ItemSchema.MimeContent); - Only for saving email as File

        // Item searches do not support Deep traversal.
        view.Traversal = ItemTraversal.Shallow;
        // Sorting
        view.OrderBy.Add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, SortDirection.Descending);

        SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection searchFilterCollection = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And);

        SearchFilter sfSentDateTime = new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThan(ItemSchema.DateTimeSent, Convert.ToDateTime("06/25/2019 4:00"));
        searchFilterCollection.Add(sfSentDateTime);

        SearchFilter sfMarkedAsUnread = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false);
        searchFilterCollection.Add(sfMarkedAsUnread);

        FindItemsResults<Item> items = inbox.FindItems(searchFilterCollection, view);

        string sXml = string.Empty;
        if (items != null && items.Any())
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (Item item in items)
            {
                item.Load(PropSet);
                EmailMessage email = (EmailMessage)item;

                if (email.Attachments.Count > 0)
                {
                    AttachmentCollection attachmentsCol = email.Attachments;
                    for (int i = 0; i < email.Attachments.Count; i++)
                    {
                        FileAttachment oAttachement = (FileAttachment)email.Attachments[i];
                        // Saving the attachment
                        oAttachement.Load("C:\\Temp\\" + oAttachement.Name);
                    }
                }
            }

            sXml = string.Format("<root>{0}</root>", sb.ToString());
        }


        }
```